# ActionListener for muliple JButton instances

Tags: java, swing, event-handling, awt, actionlistener

I got a problem when adding `ActionListener` to two `JButtons` in the following Code.

I want to print each 1 and 2 when I click on these two Buttons (b1,b2)

But I can only print 1 or 2.

Could you please give me a solution to fix this problem?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

class CCCc extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    JButton b1,b2;
    JTextField f1;

CCCc(){
    setSize(500,200);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setResizable(false);
    f1=new JTextField();
    f1.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
    add("North",f1);
    JPanel p1=new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    add(p1);

    b1=new JButton("1");    
    b1.addActionListener(this); 
    b2=new JButton("2");
    b2.addActionListener(this);
    p1.add(b1);
    p1.add(b2);

    setVisible(true);
}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    String s=f1.getText();
    f1.setText(s+"1");
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

It's a bad idea to subclass classes, such as `JFrame` and `Thread`, unnecessarily. It's also a bad idea to implement interfaces inappropriately. (Thirdly, it's a bad idea to attempt to look at the `source` of an event and the `command` is nasty as well)

I suggest switching to an anonymous inner class for the listeners. You will notice you have common code for both buttons, so that can be factored into a method requiring only a single inner class. The variable holding "1" or "2" would usually be referenced via a `final` local field in the method enclosing the anonymous inner class. However, you could use a non-anonymous class with a field accessed in the usual way.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little on why it's bad to look at the `source` of an event?

Comment: I'd suggest using the `Action` API over anonymouse classes, simple because they have greater scope for re-use and extendability, but that's just me ;) - PS - what's wrong with the using the `getActionCommand`?  It's defiantly better then using `getSource` and is how the API is suppose to be used (before the `Action` API at least)

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Action` is terrible in my opinion. It makes a real mess of code (although most GUI code seems to be incredibly badly written anyway).

Comment: Wow, you must be the first person to think that the Action API is a bad choice. Given the fact y can use the same instance/implementation for menus, buttons, key bindings and popups & beats 40+ levels of if-else statements, I'd have to (personally) disagree, but each to there own

Comment: @MadProgrammer `Action` is essentially a weird hash table. It's a joke.

Answer (score 2):

The ActionEvent parameter has much useful information that you can use including a reference to the button pressed -- via `getSource()` or to the button's text via `getActionCommand(). So you can simply get the actionCommand from the ActionEvent and  use it:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
    String s=f1.getText();
    f1.setText(s+ evt.getActionCommand());
}
```

Comment: Someone -- please justify the down-vote, and tell me how my answer is not useful or even better, how it can be improved.

Comment: I would actually suggest it's better then any of the others - IMHO (ps - `Action` API ;))

Answer (score 1):

I think the case is You want to know on which `JButton`, the A`ctionEvent` is triggered, And if it is `b1`, You have to join a `"1"` to the textfield else `"2"`.
If the case is the above, do the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt){
JButton temp=evt.getSource();
String s=f1.getText()+temp.getText();
f1.setText(s);
}
```

If the case is not the above, then I say Sorry